# DateTime accepts more than 4 digits for year

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-mvc-5

In my test application I have a datetime field defined as such:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This is required")]
[Display(Name = "test date:")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]        
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MMMM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? date1 { get; set; }
```

and in my view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(
    model => model.date1,
    new {
        htmlAttributes = new {
            @Value = Model.date1 != null ? Model.date1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : ""
        }
    })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.date1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Everything works fine but when I enter a date like 10/03/19999 (dd,MM,yyyyy), the application breaks, obviously the date I've entered is wrong but i'm not sure how to action the error. I've tried using datetime.tryparse to postback on failure but then i lose what i filled the form in with.

Update:

Following quadzz solution, I've tried:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This is required")]
[Display(Name = "test date:")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Range(typeof(DateTime), "1/1/1900", "31/12/2000", ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Why is it wrong? sure its going to be a LONG time before we get to 10000 but one day..

Comment: Define "the application breaks"

Comment: `DateTime` supports year up to 9999. If the year is more than that, it considered overflow (and may throwing exception). You can create a custom struct similar to `DateTime` with 5 digit `Year` property, but seems that you need to declare several `DateTime` methods in the struct.

Comment: So when I place a break point and use 10/09/19999 as the date, the date field is null when it hits the controller and also when I use it in my SQL query, the error is the 'field was not specified'.For a date like '10/09/1999' it works fine

Comment: What you are describing is the expected behavior. If the date is not correct how do you expect your editor to display it if you are using a date object before converting it to string? I would add some javascript validation as well, then you make sure that most users will input a valid date and from the small percentage of users who doesn't have javascript enabled and that input an incorrect date it will be handled in the server side like you do now with DateTime.TryParse. You could also change your DateTime? field to a string but I think it would be a worst solution.

Comment: i've thought of using JS to grab what they input and make sure it is valid but as you say, its client, the server side, on postback of an invalid date, the form is empty not remebering what teh user inputted

Comment: Under NO circumstance do you ever attempt to set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods (your `new { @Value = .. ` code). There are also multiple other issues with your code - your using `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` to render the browsers HTML-5 datepicker (which is only supported in Chrome and Edge) so it need to be `DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"` (ISO format) in order to work correctly.

Comment: And the view code is just `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.date1)` and you do not need a `[Range]` attribute (which does not work on the client side anyway without modifying the `$.validator`

Answer (score 2):

Try ranging your datetime field. 
Reference here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute.aspx

Example:

```
    [Range(typeof(DateTime), "1/1/2000", "1/1/2010",
        ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1:d} and {2:d}")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
```

Comment: I've tried this solution but it doesn't work? i've updated my answer to what i've done

Comment: This is wrong, and a `[Range]` attribute does not even work for dates in the client

Answer (score 1):

Perform client side validation before sending data to server. Though server side validation is also required your scenario could be handled by client side validation to do so include following js files in layout file

1. jquery
2. jquery.validate
3. jquery.validate.unobtrusive

So your view should be like

```
@Html.EditorFor(
    model => model.date1,
    new {
        htmlAttributes = new {
            @Value = Model.date1 != null ? Model.date1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : "",
            @Readonly="readonly"
        }
    })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.date1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

I have made Editor readonly so that user picks date from datepicker library (manual date entry is prohibited)[Though it can be easily bypassed]

If client side validation is passed or client submit data by disabling javascript you need to perform server side validation which can be done in controller by checking ModelState

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Employee(EmployeeModel employee)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    //Everything is good to process
  }
  return View(employee);//returns view with model error if any
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of solutions:

Add client side validation to check the date before sending it to the server (and of course keep the server validation you do now as well). Doing this you reduce your problem to an almost insignificant number of cases (those users who doesn't have javascript enabled and input a wrong date).

Or another solution:

Change your date1 field to a string.  If your date is not correct, send the original value back to your page.

```
DateTime date;

if (DateTime.TryParse(date1, out temp))    
{
    //The date is fine, save it.
}
else
{
    ModelState.AddError("date1", "Incorrect date: " + date1);
}
```

Then in your editor you just display a normal text field, don't need to make a conversion.